# Regex multiple match

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

Suppose I have the following string:   `[P6]aabbcc<em>ddeeff</em>gghhiijj<em>kkllmmnn</em>oopp[P2]qqrr<em>ssttuuww</em>xxyyzz`.
How will I extract the `<em>...</em>` tag along with the info inside square brackets, i.e, I wanted to extract the following:

`[P6]` and `<em>ddeeff</em>`

`[P6]` and `<em>kkllmmnn</em>`

`[P2]` and `<em>ssttuuww</em>`

I have tried a lot using many patterns but I am not able to find all the above matches (https://regex101.com/r/b64Wuv/1).

Does any one know how to do this with regex?

Comment: Why don't you just extract each part, and then process the rest separately by the langauae...

Comment: I'm not sure if this can actually be done with a single RegExp, even with both Lookahead and the new ECMA 2018 Lookbehind.
I think you'll need to parse this with something like [lex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lex).

Comment: this is not a regular language and can't be read as one. You should use a parser

Comment: This could be done in Java (which supports non-constant-length lookbehind assertions), but I definitely agree with other commenters that it's much better to parse such content with a dedicated parser. And the link you posted suggests you want to do it in PHP, which does not seem possible to me.

Answer (score 1):

@San, you are quite close. The pattern needs a bit more to your's as below [sample in C#]

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<Ps>\[.*?]).+?<em>(?<ems>.*?)<\/em>");
        var input = "[P6]aabbcc<em>ddeeff</em>gghhiijj<em>kkllmmnn</em>oopp[P2]qqrr<em>ssttuuww</em>xxyyzz";
        var matches = regex.Matches(input);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            if (match.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{match.Groups["Ps"].Value} {match.Groups["ems"].Value}");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use 2 regex:

1st regex - to match strings:

```
Match 1: [P6]aabbcc<em>ddeeff</em>gghhiijj<em>kkllmmnn</em>oopp
Match 2: [P2]qqrr<em>ssttuuww</em>xxyyzz
```

to achieve this use `\[[^[]+`, [example](https://regex101.com/r/b64Wuv/2).

2nd regex - to match ems:

```
Match 1: <em>ddeeff</em>
Match 2: <em>kkllmmnn</em>
```

to achieve this use `<em>([^<]+?)<\/em>`, [example](https://regex101.com/r/b64Wuv/3).